# How to set the max drag on jquery-ui

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm creating a side menu in the phonegap, I need to drag to the left with a -400px wide limit, and to the right with a 400px wide limit, the problem is that I only know to do drag between parent and without limits:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({  containment: "parent" });
```

---

or

---

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({  axis: "x" });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[Array](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment)** for defining a bounding box in `containment` like below:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    //containment: "parent"
    containment: [-400,0,400,$(document).scrollTop()+$(window).height()]
});
```

[Online Demo (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/5kwxpfxu/1/)

Comment: how to move only to the sides?